# Axios posts data to the client domain instead of server domain

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, react-redux, axios

`api.js` file

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const signIn = formData => axios.post('/auth/signin', formData);
export const signUp = formData => axios.post('/auth/signup', formData);
```

`package.json` in client

```
{
    ...
    "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

The problem here is whenever I call a method from `api.js`, the request is sent to `localhost:3000` which is where my client is running. Instead I want the request to be sent to the proxy. I don't exactly know if the thing that I'm intending to do is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same is possible.

Basically, here is what will happen: If a request is made to a URL and that URL is not maintained by the React App itself then, the request will be "redirected" towards the URL mentioned in the Proxy.

Make sure that the React App itself does not have a `/auth/signin` and `/auth/signup` route.

A common convention to differentiate API URL(s) is to prefix them with `/api`.

Thereby, making the URL to API be: `/api/user/signIn` or `/api/user/profile`.

Also, I am assuming that you have setup the React application using Create React App. If not then, the `proxy` variable will need to be set in `webpack config`.

Now, to accept the network calls, your BackEnd will need to have `CORS` enabled.

Comment: I appended `/api` to my api url and made the changes as required. Cors is also enabled but still the request is sent to `localhost:3000`

Comment: Can you attach a proof of the same? Capture the Network request using your browser console and share the screenshot.

Also, are you using Create React App?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/JW2Mznb.png
Yes, I'm using create-react-app

Comment: Share the BackEnd code with me too.

Along with that, just for testing purposes, could you please make request to the Absolute URL. Like: `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/signin`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fZce7UxR   Absolute url works fine